# "would like to find and connect to devices on your local network" error with inbound CFSocket connection

Tags: ios

We have an IOS application which *only* listens on a INADDR_ANY socket connection for inbound connection using `CFSocketCreate`/`CFSocketGetNative`/`CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource`/`CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket` etc (to display debug information via HTTP).

(So it falls into the category "Listening for and accepting incoming TCP connections").

If the first incoming socket connection happens on a new installed app we run into the error mentioned above. As we do neither use Bonjour nor `getpeername()` I wonder where the problem is. Obviously it doesn't matter how the dialog is closed, our program works. But it is of course annoying for us (QA is harder) and our customers.

Any idea what could be the problem ?
I looked into all the questions related here, but I think we are not using one of the 'banned' APIs triggering the dialog

If I set a breakpoint to the `stream:handleEvent:` function of the `NSStreamDelegate` the popup appears *before* `NSStreamEventOpenCompleted`, so it appears some internals of the NSStream processing cause this.

on the debug console this appears btw:
`[connection] nw_connection_copy_connected_path [C1] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_path on unconnected nw_connection 2022-04-06 17:28:55.811551+0200 GenMob[35630:3181485] [] tcp_connection_is_cellular No connected path`

I did fiddle together a small demo app downloadable from https://github.com/leopatras/cfsocket.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, we ended up rewriting our code to use plain Berkeley sockets together with the GCD dispatch_source machinery ... there is a working socket server sample *not* triggering the local network prompt at https://github.com/leopatras/GCDSimpleSocketServer/

The dispatch_source_zzz functions allow a similar event driven approach like the CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket function. In comparison to https://github.com/leopatras/cfsocket it needs even less code. If the local network prompt is always triggered is questionable, it may depend from other parameters such as the used dev certificate/provisioning profile.

I had an intensive exchange with the Apple support about this topic,
(they weren't able to reproduce our problem initially, but after retrying on several devices they got it too) : they did recommend using the new Network framework functions instead of Berkeley sockets (See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network?language=objc) and I tried hard to use them however I failed to create a simple reliable working echo server with those functions in obj-C (didn't try the Swift route).